# How to assign 'findandmodify' privilege to a mongo user?

Tags: mongodb

I'm running a Mongo 2.6 replica instance where a node application needs to talk to. Basically nothing much was setup except these parameters:

```
# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/db/mongodb/mongod.log

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/db/mongodb/
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# how the process runs
processManagement:
  fork: true  # fork and run in background

security:
  keyFile: /usr/local/etc/mongodb-keyfile

replication:
  replSetName: bla
```

That for the server, and on the specific DB we have defined a user:

db.createUser({user: "the_user", pwd:"blablapassword", roles:["readWrite"]})

So far everything worked fine, except this new application is trying to do something others didn't do yet, and it's failing:

```
{ [MongoError: not authorized on blablabla to execute command { findandmodify: "identitycounters", query: { field: "_id", model: "source" }, new: true, remove: false, upsert: false, update: { $set: { count: 0 } }, writeConcern: { w: 1 } }]
```

So I've been going through documentation, trying to figure out how to get that done... and without luck. No matter what I tried, I keep ending up with the same error, so I guess I'm doing something wrong.

Googling this issue, I found some recommendation to just include the role **dbAdmin**. While I don't like that as a solution, I tried it anyway out of despair and **that too didn't work.**

All I know is the **app works fine on a blank Mongo instance without replication or authorization.**

**ASK:**
Given that we do have replication and authorization in production, how can I authorize the user to do that findandmodify() command?

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: is blabla... a system database?

Comment: It's a regular database created like: 'use blabla' and then 'db.createUser({user: "the_user", pwd:"blablapassword", roles:["readWrite"]})'

Comment: Have you definitely configured the application to [authenticate when it connects to MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/)?

Comment: Long overdue but closing the topic... it seemed deep down the nodejs code, there was a username and password hardcoded that did not use the user we had listed in the config files. Didn't take until now to figure out, but I forgot to update this thread. Hope it still is worth it. Bottomline: for findandmodify() the readWrite role will do. If it doesn't, then for sure your app is using a different username, even though everyone else may claim it's not ;-) .